# Compute $H^1(X,\Bbb{Z}_U)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X = \mathbb{A}^1_k$ with $k$ infinite and $U = X - \{P,Q\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_U= i_{!}(\mathbb{Z}|_U)$, $\Bbb{Z}$ the constant sheaf. I want to say that $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}_U) \neq 0$. If it is zero we see exact sequence

$$0 \to H^0(X,\mathbb{Z}_U) \to H^0(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^0(X,\mathbb{Z}_{\{P,Q\}} ) \to0$$

where $\mathbb{Z}_Y$ is $j_\ast(\mathbb{Z}|_{\{P,Q\}})$. The middle term is $\mathbb{Z}$ but can I say right term is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$? It seems like it's actually $\mathbb{Z}$. I am confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your sheaf $\mathbb{Z}_{\{P,Q\}}$ is equal to $j_\ast(\mathbb{Z}|_{\{P,Q\}})$, we have : $$H^0(X,\mathbb{Z}_{\{P,Q\}} ) =H^0(X, j_\ast(\mathbb{Z}|_{\{P,Q\}}))\stackrel {definition}{=}H^0(\{P,Q\}, \mathbb{Z}_X|_{\{P,Q\}})\stackrel {!}{=} H^0(\{P,Q\}, \mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$$ This indeed shows that your displayed sequence is not exact (since $H^0(X,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb  Z$ and  $\mathbb Z$ cannot be surjected onto $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$) and thus that necessarily  $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}_U) \neq 0$.

**Edit**
It is actually fairly easy to see that  $ H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})=0 $ (because constant sheaves are flasque and thus acyclic on irreducible spaces), and that $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}_U) \cong \mathbb Z$ since it is the cokernel of the restriction morphism  $ H^0(X,\mathbb{Z})= \mathbb{Z} \to H^0(\{P,Q\},\mathbb{Z} )=\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}: n\mapsto (n,n)$

**New edit**
As discussed in the comments I have used that the restriction of a constant sheaf $A_X$ on a space $X$ to any subspace $Y$ is the constant sheaf $A_Y$  to deduce $H^0(\{P,Q\}, \mathbb{Z_X}|_{\{P,Q\}})\stackrel {!}{=} H^0(\{P,Q\}, \mathbb{Z})$

Comment: Thank you for answer. I know $H^0(X,j_\ast(\Bbb{Z}|_{\{P,Q\}})) = H^0(\{P,Q\}, \Bbb{Z}|_{\{P,Q\}})$ but  why is this equal to $\Bbb{Z} \oplus \Bbb{Z}$? By definition $H^0(\{P,Q\}, \Bbb{Z}|_{\{P,Q\}}) = \varinjlim_{U \supseteq \{P,Q\}} \Bbb{Z}(U)$, every term in the limit is just $\Bbb{Z}$ so how you get $\Bbb{Z} \oplus \Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: Dear Dylan,  $H^0(\{P,Q\}, \mathbb{Z})=\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z=\mathbb Z^2$ because $\{P,Q\}$ is a discrete space and for a discrete topological space $D$ and a a constant sheaf $C$ on $D$, we have $H^0(D, C)=C^D$

Comment: However there is small subtlety because what we have is $H^0(\{P,Q\},\Bbb{Z}|_{\{P,Q\}})$ and not $H^0(\{P,Q\},\Bbb{Z})$. Is it true that $\Bbb{Z}|_{\{P,Q\}}$ is just constant sheaf on $\{P,Q\}$?

Comment: Yes there is a subtlety and yes the restriction of a constant sheaf to **any** subspace is a constant sheaf. My favourite way for seeing this is by interpreting sheaves as étalé spaces: a very old-fashioned point of view which I claim should not be dismissed as an irrelevant historical oddity.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is wrong with my reasoning: $H^0(\{P,Q\},\Bbb{Z}|_{\{P,Q\}}) = \varinjlim_{U \supseteq \{P,Q\}} \Bbb{Z}(U)$ by definition. For *every* open set $U$ containing $\{P,Q\}$, $\Bbb{Z}(U) = \Bbb{Z}$. Why is the limit (and hence global sections) not just $\Bbb{Z}$? This is what is confusing me.

Comment: The formula in the reasoning in your last comment is not correct: the sections of a  sheaf restricted to a subspace $D$ are **not** given (in general) by the direct limit of the sections on open neighbourhoods of $D$. You **have to first compute the  sheaf restricted to $D$**. Here the restricted sheaf is the constant sheaf $\mathbb Z$ on $D=\{P,Q\}$.

Comment: I see where I am wrong, what I have defined there is just the inverse image *presheaf* and not the sheaf itself. The inverse image presheaf in this case is the constant presheaf, and the sheafification of this is indeed the constant sheaf on $\{P,Q\}$. I got it now, thanks for your patience Mr. Georges.

Comment: Dear Dylan, I'm happy that I could help you and that we now see eye to eye. And, yes, the difficulty with the now fashionable definition of restriction of a sheaf is (as you quite correctly described)  that you first have to define a presheaf through a process involving a direct limit and then sheafify that presheaf. That's why I like the old *étalé space* approach.